# Referencing layer in table of contents using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a plugin for QGIS using python, But need some help. I want to 1.Zoom to a layer and 2. make the layer visible(switch off or on).

But I have managed to zoom to an active layer by setting the active layer in the map canvas by using.

```
import qgis
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
acl = canvas.layer(1)
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(acl)
> True
qgis.utils.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

But this only work as long as the layer is viable(obviously since I use canvas). So I need another way to "point" to a layer and then zoom to and switch off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of [QgsMapCanvas.setExtent()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a9ce3b0d7d264e347c64fcafbaf779ea0), [QgsMapLayerRegistry](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html) (Use `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()` to get access, since it's a singleton) to find your layer and [QgsMapLayer.extent()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a495da0b58296b5fb25ca10a8b30841c0) to get its extent.

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer( 'YourLayerId' )
canvas.setExtent( vl.extent() )
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I was looking for.However I'm not mush of a programmer and I am struggling some what to get this to work. If you have an example that will be great, but thanks again for the help.

Comment: I added a minimal example. I need to know more about your setup to be able to extend it, so if you have specific questions, the example can be extended. E.g. based on your problem you could also get the reference to the vectorlayer (simly called `vl` in the example) in a different way. Also I'm not sure about the "switch off" part. I assume it's about visibility, but you mention it at a place where you said before it's already invisible...